# MongoDB: executionTimeMillis increased when adding index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am pretty confused to why making the searched fields to be "index" is making the query "theoretically" slower.

I have a not very big collection of items (6240) and all of them have the following structure.

```js
const SomeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    data: String,
    from: {
        type: Number,
    },
    to: {
        type: Number,
    },
    timeStamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    }
})

SomeSchema.set('toJSON', {
    getters: true,
    transform: (doc, ret) => {
        delete ret.from
        delete ret.to
        return sanitizeSensitiveProperties(ret)
    }
})

export const Some = mongoose.model('Some', SomeSchema, 'somethings')
```

The strange thing came when after trying to improve the query I changed the schema to be

```js
...
    from: {
        type: Number,
        index: true
    },
    to: {
        type: Number,
        index: true
    },
...
```

With this schema I run the following query

```js
db.rolls.find({from: {$lte: 1560858984}, to: {$gte: 1560858984}}).explain("executionStats")
```

This are the results **NOTE THAT THE 1st ONE is the one without index**

```
"executionTimeMillis" : 6,
"totalKeysExamined" : 0,
"totalDocsExamined" : 6240,
```

```
"executionTimeMillis" : 15,
"totalKeysExamined" : 2895,
"totalDocsExamined" : 2895,
```

Does this result make any sense, or is just the mongo `.explain()` function messing around?

As you can see I am using the `Mongoose` Driver in the version ^5.5.13 and I am using `Mongo` in the version 4.0.5

Comment: I would say this is normal. How many times did you run the `find` query? I find that running each query 10-20 times resulted in very similar execution time eventually, due to warm cache. Also, the documents are very small, plus the difference you posted is only about 9ms, which is arguably not significant. Note that you can't project this result to a larger query involving millions of large documents that won't fit in your RAM. In that case, indexed vs. non-indexed would be very different.